# JavaBeans giving result only once

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I'm having a problem displaying an error message using beans. This is what i'm trying to do on a login page:

- get email, password and role of a user and using beans check it against the database for validation.
- if in case there are any errors, it is added to the error bean and displayed to user. Currently, i'm just testing if the user enters email or not.

The problem that i'm getting is: everytime i turn off tomcat and rerun it, first time i dont enter the email in the email field, the error is displayed. After that if i once entered a value in the email field. The error message will never show again(ofcourse when i dont enter email in email field)

Here is my code:

doLogin.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="com.skf.setup.data.userData.userData" %>   
<jsp:useBean id="loginFormData" class = "com.skf.setup.data.form.loginForm" scope="session" />
<jsp:useBean id="userData" class="com.skf.setup.data.userData.userData" scope="session" />
<jsp:useBean id="userDataBean" class="com.skf.setup.data.userData.userDataBean" scope="session" />
<jsp:useBean id="errorData" class="com.skf.setup.data.error.formError" scope="request" />
<jsp:setProperty name = "loginFormData" property="*" />

<jsp:include page="/setup/layout/header/include.jsp" />
<title>Login - SKF Cassino Database</title>
</head>
<body style="background: #006687;">

    <div class="container">
        <!-- LOGIN FORM -->
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="doLogin.jsp" role="form">
            <div class="login">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">
                            <img class="login-panel" alt="SKF logo"
                                src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/setup/include/img/skf-logo-white.png"> Cassino Database
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <% if(request.getParameter("login")!=null)
                        {
                        out.println("Text");
                            if(userData.validate(loginFormData,errorData)==true)
                            {
                            //  out.println("Text2");
                                userData udata = new userData();
                                userData.setData((String)loginFormData.getEmail(), udata); 
                            //  userData.setEmail((String)loginFormData.getEmail());
                                out.println(udata.getId());
                            }
                        }
%>
                    <div class="panel-body">Accedi  
                    <% for(String currError: errorData.getGenErrors())
                        out.println(currError);
                    %>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 350px; margin: 10px auto;">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="username@email.com"
                            class="form-control" name="email" /> 
                            <br>
                            <input  type="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control" name="password" required />
                             <br>
                            <select class="form-control" name="role">
                            <option selected>Role</option>
                            <option value="acquisti" >Acquisti</option>
                            <option value="SF" >Solution Factory</option>
                            <option value="cassino" >SKF Cassino</option>
                        </select>
                         <br>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value= "Entra" name="login" type="submit" />
                        <input class="btn btn-warning" value="Annulla" type="reset" />

                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!-- LOGIN FORM ENDS HERE-->


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

formError.java

```
/**
 *  package that is used to display errors on the fly after being added
 */
package com.skf.setup.data.error;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
/**
 * @author NADIR Ibrahim
 *
 */
public class formError 
{
    private ArrayList<String> genError;
    private HashMap<String,String> fieldErrors;

    public formError()
    {
        this.genError = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.fieldErrors = new HashMap<String,String>();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getGenErrors() {
        return genError;
    }

    public void setGenError(String error) {
        this.genError.add(error);
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getFieldErrors() {
        return fieldErrors;
    }

    public void setFieldErrors(HashMap<String, String> fieldErrors) {
        this.fieldErrors = fieldErrors;
    }

    public void addFieldErrors(String field,String error)
    {
        if(this.fieldErrors.containsKey(field) || !this.fieldErrors.isEmpty())
        {
            this.fieldErrors.put(field,error);
        }
        else if(this.fieldErrors.containsKey(field))
        {
            this.fieldErrors.remove(field);
            this.fieldErrors.put(field,error);
        }
    } 

    public String getFieldErrors(String field)
    {
        return fieldErrors.get(field);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        boolean empty = true;
        if(!genError.isEmpty() && !fieldErrors.isEmpty())
            empty = false;
        return empty;
    }

    public boolean hasFieldError()
    {
        boolean hasError = false;
        if(!fieldErrors.isEmpty())
            hasError = true;
        return hasError;
    }

    public boolean hasFieldError(String field)
    {
        boolean hasError = false;
        if(!fieldErrors.get(field).isEmpty() || fieldErrors.get(field)!=null)
            hasError = true;
        return hasError;
    }

}
```

validate function

```
public boolean validate(loginForm value,formError error)
    {
        boolean valid = false;
        String email = value.getEmail();
        String password = value.getPassword();
        String role = value.getRole();

        //check if values are entered by user or not, if not add error to error map and notify user
        if(email.isEmpty()) 
        {
            //TODO ADD ERROR TO HASHMAP
            error.setGenError("Email is necessary!");
        }
        if(password.isEmpty())
        {
            //TODO ADD ERROR TO HASHMAP
        }
        if(role.isEmpty())
        {
            //TODO ADD ERROR TO HASHMAP
        }

        //check if values entered by user are valid or not
        if(!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty() && !role.isEmpty())
        {
        Connection c = DBConnection.dbConnect();
        String sql = "SELECT email,password,role FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=? AND role=?";   
        PreparedStatement ps;
        try {
            ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1,(String)value.getEmail());
            ps.setString(2,(String)value.getPassword());
            ps.setString(3,(String)value.getRole());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next())
            {
                valid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //TODO ADD ERROR THAT USER ID AND PASSWORD ARE WRONG
            }
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            DBConnection.closeCon(c);
        }
        }

        return valid;
    }
```

I'm new to Beans and currently learning. I tried changing the function names like `addGenError` instead of `setGenError` and it the behavior was the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the issue:

while sending form data, i'm using the bean id: `loginFormData` which is set to session scope. After changing it to request, i got my desired functionality.

Changed code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="loginFormData" class = "com.skf.setup.data.form.loginForm" scope="request" />
```